# How can I put a Twitter "tweet" in my Blog

Tags: twitter, wordpress, blog

Currently I think I would just screen shot a popular tweet from [@aplusk](http://twitter.com/aplusk) or someone else I am trying to reference but

1. I am always stuck with cropping
2. People say I could have "photoshopped" it and it is not real
3. I have to link the tweet link to the image but any links inside the image I cannot link.

Is there something an app or a Plugin that I can just place it "live" into my Blog (so it shows just like on Twitter) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blackbird Pie (now defunct) used to do exactly what you are looking for: simply paste the URL of any tweet into the form on that page and it will generate static HTML that you can embed into your blog.

You can now embed directly via the Twitter UI by clicking "Embed this Tweet"

[image: Embed the Tweet]

There is additionally a [Wordpress specific plugin](http://themergency.com/twitter-blackbird-pie-wordpress-plugin/) as well as a [Google Chrome extension](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/embed-tweets-in-2-seconds-blackbird-pie-chrome-extension.html) for using Blackbird Pie.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there's also a Twitter-web app you can find via their site, that allows you to embed a user-specific timeline via html.
It's not static, since it's basically just a miniature timeline window, but it sure looks genuine and non-photoshopped :)

EDIT:

Now I also found [the Link](http://twitter.com/goodies/widget_profile) :)

(Scroll down on the Twitter main page and look for "goodies" in the footer.)

Comment: It would be great if you can add the link to this (Are you talking about *Anywhere*) :D

Comment: done :)
couldn't find the link at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twitter's [embed-this-tweet code](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets), but there's one little challenge with the way that Blogger's post-editor strips out `<p>` tags.

It is possible though. I started an article about this ages ago and got distracted—just finished it for you now: http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.ie/2012/06/put-working-twitter-messages-in-blogger.html

Comment: While we at SE appreciate your answers and time, a lot of your answers tend to link back to your site. Please see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion on how to promote your own blog on the SE Network.

Comment: I'm here because I want to build up a reputation so that when I ask a question that I can't work out the answer to, I will be more likely to get an answer.   Sorry if that's the "wrong" reason.   I only answer questions that I'm certain that I know the answers to.    Usually, but not always, that means about issues that I've researched and written up.   Sorry if that upsets you - I'll leave out the links in future.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with linking to your site :) as long as it's not the main thing you do here. It doesn't upset me, I only act on [flags](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#flagging) I receive in mod queue.